# Boost 1_52 build VS2012 Failed

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to build the Boost 1_52 library with VS2012.  Everything is building fine except for the Date Time dll (boost_date_time-vc110-mt-1_52.dll).

I'm using B2.exe as shown below
b2.exe toolset=msvc-11.0 --build-type=complete stage debug-symbols=on debug-store=database --abbreviate-paths

I've tried using cxxflags="/Y- " because I get other out of date PDB errors, this didn't change anything.  I've tried setting Zm100, again no change.

When it gets to the gregorian section, I get a number of failures like shown below

common.mkdir bin.v2\libs\date_time\build\msvc-11.0\debug\debug-store-database\threading-multi
common.mkdir bin.v2\libs\date_time\build\msvc-11.0\debug\debug-store-database\threading-multi\gregorian
compile-c-c++ bin.v2\libs\date_time\build\msvc-11.0\debug\debug-store-database\threading-multi\gregorian\greg_month.obj
greg_month.cpp
libs\date_time\src\gregorian\greg_month.cpp : fatal error C1033: cannot open program database 'd:\boost\source\boost_1_52_0\gregorian\greg_month.pdb'

```
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x86 >nul
```

cl /Zm800 -nologo @"bin.v2\libs\date_time\build\msvc-11.0\debug\debug-store-database\threading-multi\gregorian\greg_month.obj.rsp"

Comment: Does d:\boost\source\boost_1_52_0\gregorian\greg_month.pdb exist on disk?

Comment: No, this file does not exist.  I'm not sure how I would go about trying to build greg_month.cpp individually to see what the problem is.

Comment: Of the following three lines in the output logs of the build, only the last one fails.
'compile-c-c++ bin.v2\libs\date_time\build\msvc-11.0\rls\adrs-mdl-64\dbg-str-dtbs\dbg-symbl-on\lnk-sttc\rntm-lnk-sttc\thrd-mlt\gregorian\greg_month.obj'

'compile-c-c++ bin.v2\libs\date_time\build\msvc-11.0\rls\adrs-mdl-64\dbg-str-dtbs\dbg-symbl-on\lnk-sttc\rntm-lnk-sttc\gregorian\greg_month.obj'

'compile-c-c++ bin.v2\libs\date_time\build\msvc-11.0\rls\adrs-mdl-64\dbg-str-dtbs\dbg-symbl-on\thrd-mlt\gregorian\greg_month.obj'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the build is trying to place the .pdb files for some object files of the `date_time` library in a non-existent directory.

You can work around the problem by doing:

```
md gregorian
```

before performing the build so the directory exists.

I'm not sure yet what the real fix is since the boost build system is more or less a black box to me.

Comment: I haven't played much with the boost build process either, but in looking at the Jamfile.v2 in $root\libs\date_time\build, the line 
"lib boost_date_time : gregorian/$(CPP_SOURCES).cpp;"
is different then the other build files. Looking at chrono and serialization, neither of those have a prefix directory, they just use the root directory.